# Pulsing a LED array to ground

Tags: mosfet

I have a LED array (30 V, 0.7 A) powered by a variable power supply.

At the moment I pulse with a [ZK-PP1K](https://www.ledsales.com.au/pdf/ZK-PP2K.pdf) pulse modulator through an IRF530A FET. When ON, the pulse goes directly to the LED array. It works - great.

However, the power is switched on and off from the power supply on each pulse and:

1. I am not sure it's good for the power supply
2. I cannot set the current when pulsing (it varies fast)
3. There may be a ramp-up time on each pulse from the power supply

I think that I need the IRF530A FET to pulse to ground so that the current/voltage from the power supply remains constant both when the LED is ON or OFF.

Could someone draw me the circuit for this?

There is a ground terminal on the power supply. Do I have to ground the FET output to power supply ground?

Comment: Could you please show some schematics of your described circuit?

Comment: Do you have any indication that this is damaging the power supply in any way?  Crowbarring the power supply will neither keep the power constant nor solve any of the other things you think it will.  If you are concerned with keeping the current constant, you should be thinking about an inductor or some other energy storage device.  Sizing will depend on pulse frequency, duty cycle, etc.

Comment: I have no evidence of power supply damaging.  The Zk-PP1K is variable frequency and duty cycle.   How would a inductor work?   Example of circuit?  Should I measure the voltage going to the LED with a oscilloscope if it is constant with a reasonable square wave?

Comment: I have just realized that grounding the FET stills pulls the power supply to 0V.

Comment: I have just realized that grounding the MOSFET stills pulls the power supply to 0V.    How about 2 FETs.   One powers the LED array normally.   The other I invert the pulse, then feed it to the second MOSFET.  I send the output from this MOSFET through a power resistor of about the same resistance as the LED array.  30V/0.7A = 42 Ohms. Would this work as one MOSFET is on while the other is off.   And power dissipation is about the same?